# Objective C - How to call class methods without allocating and initializing an object

Tags: objective-c, init, alloc

I'm new to Objective-C and I'm finding the syntax of valid Objective-C code hard to understand. For example, all objects are normally allocated and initialized using the MyClass *myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init]; syntax. However, in the example below, a method is called on the "NSKeyedArchiver" class before creating an initialized object of that class. The same situation happens in the next line of code, where a method is called on "NSUserDefaults" without creating an allocated/initialized object. How is this possible?

```
NSData *bandObjectData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.bandObject];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bandObjectData forKey:bandObjectKey];
```

Thanks!

Comment: `[ClassName theClassMethodName]` is how it's done.  Just like static methods in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called class methods and they don't require an instance of a class to be performed because they don't depend on an actual class instance.  You can actually create your own by prefacing the method with a + sign (as opposed to a - sign)

We generally use class methods when we don't depend on an instance of a class.  So in your examples, the NSKeyedArchiver class doesn't need an instance of itself to be created in order to archive data.  Similarly, you can get the standard NSUserDefaults without having a NSUserDefaults object created.

The other types of methods (instance methods) are used when the object itself needs to change its state.

Comment: Your first sentence is a bit inaccurate: the class itself is in fact an object.